# Wracking my brain for the word meaning "to have started on the path to the end result..."

Tags: single-word-requests

Edit: answered in comment from Dan - *anticipated* is what I was after.

Reading a recent paper in the mathematics field, the result seemed familiar, and indeed, I found in a paper I had from 25 years prior with pretty much the same result.

I thought "this presaged / predated / foreshadowed ... that.", but I'm sure there's a much more precise word for the context that eludes me (as in, I'm *sure* I've seen the desired word in that context used before).

I've been scouring thesauri with no joy, any ideas?

Comment: It would help if I knew what "this" and "that" referred to.  Does "this" mean reading an already-proved result, and does "that" refer to the feeling you got that you'd see the result before?

Comment: Academics prefer the term *anticipated* in this context.

Comment: @DanBron Yes! Oh, when the neurons conspire to frustrate... post as answer if you'd like, will happily accept.

Comment: I would, but at a quick look, I can't find a dictionary to cite for this sense.  I'm sure I've seen a Devil's-dictionary style humorous glossary of academic terms which defines it something like "invented before me", but I can't seem to find that now.

Comment: @Dan Bron check oxforddictionaries.com, one of the examples they provide is "Bolzano's theories of mathematical infinity anticipated Georg Cantor's theory of infinite sets."

Comment: @barbecue Oh, nice! Thank you.  I'll add an answer now. (Still wish I could find that snide glossary: it really was funny.)

Comment: Predated.  (Pronunciation is like this: 'pre-dated'.)

Comment: @DanBron I'd venture you're thinking of Beach's "Words for the wise"... not at my home where my copy is to verify entry, but it certainly is a Bierce style academic words humor chest...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In academic circles, the preferred term is ***anticipate***.

From [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/anticipate) (Oxford Dictionaries Online: thanks to [@barbecue for the citation](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/274986/wracking-my-brain-for-the-word-meaning-to-have-started-on-the-path-to-the-end-r/275002#comment606974_274986)):

> ***anticipate***: *Act as a forerunner or precursor of*
>
> - He *anticipated* Bates’s theories on mimicry and protective coloration
> - While he professed a disdain for pure theory, Giblin *anticipated* some elements of the relationship between trade, national income, and employment that informed Keynesian economics.
> - His theory of imperialism *anticipated* European unification and contradictions associated today with globalization of production and markets.
> - Bolzano's theories of mathematical infinity *anticipated* Georg Cantor's theory of infinite sets.

This last example sentence appears to match your situation to a tee.